# Creating a Terminal Server which can save to CSV or Excel

Tags: excel, csv, terminal

I apologize if this has been asked before but I cannot determine a search term to find it.

We have barcode scanners which we would like to use for inventory control but our point of sale / inventory system is not equipped to handle the type of inventory scanning we are doing.

I need to connect to either a Windows or Linux terminal which can save information to a CSV file or XLS file.
Something with a basic format of:

```
Scan Barcode, enter a number for the count, Enter.
Repeat
```

The intended output can be as simple as:

```
BARCODE1,5
BARCODE2,72
BARCODE3,42
BARCODE1,12
BARCODE4,6
```

Which I can then use Excel to later manipulate and add **BARCODE1,5** and **BARCODE1,12** to get a total inventory of 17.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Have you tried directly scanning into Excel? If your scanner sends a carriage return at the end of the scanned barcode then it should be pretty straightforward...

Comment: The scanner must connect to a terminal for functionality, it does not output directly to a screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just shooting from the hip here, assuming your barcode scanners connect to a Windows OS platform that supports Powershell you could try something like:

```
PS> $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,9600,None,8,one
PS> $port.Open()
PS> $port.ReadLine() | Export-CSV c:\barcodedata.csv
```

If you can give details about your barcode scanners model and accompanying software a more detailed plan might be craftable.

Generally I would expect the barcode scanner software that came with your scanners should have some functionality to allow export to a file, or you could search for open-source software that works with your model scanner.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried directly scanning into Excel? If your scanner sends a carriage return at the end of the scanned barcode then it should be pretty straightforward.

If you scan into column A then you can use this macro in the sheet's code module to position the selection correctly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set Target = Target.Cells(1)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
    End If
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        Target.Offset(1, -1).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

1. Change in "barcode" column positions to next cell over for entering amount
2. Change in "amount" column positions to barcode column, next row down