# Attempting to scan a barcode and split the entry into 2 cells

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't found anything specific, so please forgive me if this has been addressed.
I have a spreadsheet set up for the user to scan a barcode (Code128).  I need the spreadsheet to automatically place the first 13 digits in the next empty cell in column A, and the remaining characters (10 characters) in the adjacent cell in column B.
I've seen the user of left and right in formulas but haven't determined how to do this in VBA.

Comment: You can use the worksheet's Change event - plenty of examples here of that.  egs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148852/excel-and-visual-basic-barcode-in-out-checkout-system/70150844#70150844  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107591/creating-a-terminal-server-which-can-save-to-csv-or-excel/22107821#22107821

Comment: Is the scanning process done in A:A column? If so, what if the scan is not done in the first empty row? Let me check if correctly understood the question, by an example: You scan in cell "A5". Ten digits of the scanned code will go in "A6" and the rest of digits in "B6". Should this understanding be a correct one?

Comment: The more I look at it, in order for this to work, I would need a userform textbox, then the scan would go (specifically) with the first 18 digits into the first empty cell in column A, the last 10 digits would go in adjacent cell in B.

Answer (score 1):

Please, copy the next code in the sheet code module where the scanning is done:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
   If Target.Column = 1 Then
      If Len(Target.Value) > 10 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
          Target.Offset(1).Value = left(Target.Value, 10) 'place first 10 digits in the next cell
          Target.Offset(1, 1).Value = Right(Target.Value, Len(Target.Value) - 10) 'and the rest on the next row, column B:B
          Target.Offset(2).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True 'select next cell to scan in
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Before start scanning, if the barcode content is numeric, you should format columns "A:A" and "B:B" as text, but using `TextToColumns` (one column at a time). Pressing `Next`, `Next`, check `Text` and press `Finish`.

**Edited**:

The next version keep the first 10 digits in the cell where the scan has been done, and rest of the digits in column B:B, `Target` row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change_(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
   If Target.Column = 1 Then
      If Len(Target.Value) > 10 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
          Target.Offset(1).Value = left(Target.Value, 10)
          Target.Offset(1, 1).Value = Right(Target.Value, Len(Target.Value) - 10)
          Target.Offset(2).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The code that you have works, however; it scans the barcode into one cell, then on the next cell down it places the information in the cells, I need everything to happen in only 2 cells.  I believe I'm going to need to end up and place this into a userform textbox.  Here they will scan the barcode, it will transfer the first 18 characters into the next blank on column A and the last 10 characters in the adjacent cell in column B.

Comment: @B Sager  You wrote "to automatically place the first 13 digits **in the next empty cell** in column A, and the remaining characters (10 characters) in the adjacent cell". What do you want, in fact. To remain first 10 digits in the cell where the scan has been done and the rest in the next column, the same row? If you want doing something different (userform textbox etc.), try not posting such a question here. We are not bored and anxious to do something in VBA, even if not needed.

Comment: @B Sager Please, test the new version (after **Edit**) and send some feedback.

Comment: I need the first digits to be in the next empty cell in A with the remaining digits to be placed adjacent to that in column B.

Comment: @B Sager But, this is exactly what the code does! Didn't you test it? **What does it** instead of **what you want**?